# How to rename a file in Amazon S3 Bucket?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to rename a file in S3 Bucket.  Here is a code snippet

```
    S3Object s3Obj  = getS3Client().getObject(new GetObjectRequest(getBucketName(), fileName));  
//Error in Above Line itself            
    getS3Client().putObject(getBucketName(), newFileName, s3Obj.getObjectContent(), s3Obj.getObjectMetadata());

private AmazonS3 getS3Client(){
        AWSCredentials myCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AccessKey,SecretKey);
        AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(myCredentials);
        return s3client;
}
```

So, I am getting this error,

DEBUG [main] request.handleErrorResponse(748) | Received error response: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: null, AWS Request ID: AD2F31F1133A650E, AWS Error Code: AccessDenied.

I am unable to get the s3object itself.  Any suggestions or ideas how I will get S3 Object and rename it.
Thanks in Anticipation for you help.

Comment: Thanks.  I changed to `getS3Client().copyObject(getBucketName(), oldPhotoName, getBucketName(), "vignesh");`  But now also I am getting same error.  `Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 874B8E8905B026CC, AWS Error Code: AccessDenied, AWS Error Message: Access Denied` Can you please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rename files and folder in Amazon S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184720/how-to-rename-files-and-folder-in-amazon-s3)

Answer (score 35):

Direct renaming of S3 objects [is not possible](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectsExamples.html)

> Rename objects by copying them and deleting the original ones

You can copy and delete using e.g.

```
CopyObjectRequest copyObjRequest = new CopyObjectRequest(bucketName, 
           keyName, bucketName, destinationKeyName);
s3client.copyObject(copyObjRequest);
s3client.deleteObject(new DeleteObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName));
```

Comment: the above code will only copy the files but not child folders.

Answer (score 3):

As answered by High6 direct renaming of s3 is not possible, but his code will not copy all the contents

i have attached a code snippet which will copy all the contents

code is working just add your aws access key and secret key

here's what i did in code

-> copy the source folder contents(nested child and folders) and pasted in the destination folder

-> when the copying is complete, delete the source folder

```
package com.bighalf.doc.amazon;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CopyObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectSummary;

public class Test {

public static boolean renameAwsFolder(String bucketName,String keyName,String newName) {
    boolean result = false;
    try {
        AmazonS3 s3client = getAmazonS3ClientObject();
        List<S3ObjectSummary> fileList = s3client.listObjects(bucketName, keyName).getObjectSummaries();
        //some meta data to create empty folders start
        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentLength(0);
        InputStream emptyContent = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]);
        //some meta data to create empty folders end

        //final location is the locaiton where the child folder contents of the existing folder should go
        String finalLocation = keyName.substring(0,keyName.lastIndexOf('/')+1)+newName;
        for (S3ObjectSummary file : fileList) {
            String key = file.getKey();
            //updating child folder location with the newlocation
            String destinationKeyName = key.replace(keyName,finalLocation);
            if(key.charAt(key.length()-1)=='/'){
                //if name ends with suffix (/) means its a folders
                PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, destinationKeyName, emptyContent, metadata);
                s3client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
            }else{
                //if name doesnot ends with suffix (/) means its a file
                CopyObjectRequest copyObjRequest = new CopyObjectRequest(bucketName, 
                        file.getKey(), bucketName, destinationKeyName);
                s3client.copyObject(copyObjRequest);
            }
        }
        boolean isFodlerDeleted = deleteFolderFromAws(bucketName, keyName);
        return isFodlerDeleted;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

public static boolean deleteFolderFromAws(String bucketName, String keyName) {
    boolean result = false;
    try {
        AmazonS3 s3client = getAmazonS3ClientObject();
        //deleting folder children
        List<S3ObjectSummary> fileList = s3client.listObjects(bucketName, keyName).getObjectSummaries();
        for (S3ObjectSummary file : fileList) {
            s3client.deleteObject(bucketName, file.getKey());
        }
        //deleting actual passed folder
        s3client.deleteObject(bucketName, keyName);
        result = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    intializeAmazonObjects();
    boolean result = renameAwsFolder(bucketName, keyName, newName);
    System.out.println(result);
}

private static AWSCredentials credentials = null;
private static AmazonS3 amazonS3Client = null;
private static final String ACCESS_KEY = "";
private static final String SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "";
private static final String bucketName = "";
private static final String keyName = "";
//renaming folder c to x from key name
private static final String newName = "";

public static void intializeAmazonObjects() {
    credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);
    amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
}

public static AmazonS3 getAmazonS3ClientObject() {
    return amazonS3Client;
}
```

}