# How to rename spark data frame output file in AWS in spark SCALA

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, multipleoutputs

I am saving my spark data frame output as csv file in scala with partitions.
This is how i do that in **Zeppelin**.

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

    import sqlContext.implicits._
    import org.apache.spark.{ SparkConf, SparkContext }
    import java.sql.{Date, Timestamp}
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.input_file_name
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_extract

val get_cus_val = spark.udf.register("get_cus_val", (filePath: String) => filePath.split("\\.")(3))

val rdd = sc.textFile("s3://trfsmallfffile/FinancialLineItem/MAIN")
val header = rdd.filter(_.contains("LineItem.organizationId")).map(line => line.split("\\|\\^\\|")).first()
val schema = StructType(header.map(cols => StructField(cols.replace(".", "_"), StringType)).toSeq)
val data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd.filter(!_.contains("LineItem.organizationId")).map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split("\\|\\^\\|").toSeq)), schema)

val schemaHeader = StructType(header.map(cols => StructField(cols.replace(".", "."), StringType)).toSeq)
val dataHeader = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd.filter(!_.contains("LineItem.organizationId")).map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split("\\|\\^\\|").toSeq)), schemaHeader)

val df1resultFinal=data.withColumn("DataPartition", get_cus_val(input_file_name))
val rdd1 = sc.textFile("s3://trfsmallfffile/FinancialLineItem/INCR")
val header1 = rdd1.filter(_.contains("LineItem.organizationId")).map(line => line.split("\\|\\^\\|")).first()
val schema1 = StructType(header1.map(cols => StructField(cols.replace(".", "_"), StringType)).toSeq)
val data1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd1.filter(!_.contains("LineItem.organizationId")).map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split("\\|\\^\\|").toSeq)), schema1)


import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("LineItem_organizationId", "LineItem_lineItemId").orderBy($"TimeStamp".cast(LongType).desc) 
val latestForEachKey = data1.withColumn("rank", rank().over(windowSpec)).filter($"rank" === 1).drop("rank", "TimeStamp")


val dfMainOutput = df1resultFinal.join(latestForEachKey, Seq("LineItem_organizationId", "LineItem_lineItemId"), "outer")
      .select($"LineItem_organizationId", $"LineItem_lineItemId",
        when($"DataPartition_1".isNotNull, $"DataPartition_1").otherwise($"DataPartition").as("DataPartition"),
        when($"StatementTypeCode_1".isNotNull, $"StatementTypeCode_1").otherwise($"StatementTypeCode").as("StatementTypeCode"),
        when($"FinancialConceptLocalId_1".isNotNull, $"FinancialConceptLocalId_1").otherwise($"FinancialConceptLocalId").as("FinancialConceptLocalId"),
        when($"FinancialConceptGlobalId_1".isNotNull, $"FinancialConceptGlobalId_1").otherwise($"FinancialConceptGlobalId").as("FinancialConceptGlobalId"),
        when($"FinancialConceptCodeGlobalSecondaryId_1".isNotNull, $"FinancialConceptCodeGlobalSecondaryId_1").otherwise($"FinancialConceptCodeGlobalSecondaryId").as("FinancialConceptCodeGlobalSecondaryId"),
        when($"FFAction_1".isNotNull, $"FFAction_1").otherwise($"FFAction|!|").as("FFAction|!|"))
        .filter(!$"FFAction|!|".contains("D|!|"))

val dfMainOutputFinal = dfMainOutput.na.fill("").select($"DataPartition",$"StatementTypeCode",concat_ws("|^|", dfMainOutput.schema.fieldNames.filter(_ != "DataPartition").map(c => col(c)): _*).as("concatenated"))

val headerColumn = dataHeader.columns.toSeq

val header = headerColumn.mkString("", "|^|", "|!|").dropRight(3)

val dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull = dfMainOutputFinal.withColumn("concatenated", regexp_replace(col("concatenated"), "|^|null", "")).withColumnRenamed("concatenated", header)


dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull.repartition(1).write.partitionBy("DataPartition","StatementTypeCode")
  .format("csv")
  .option("nullValue", "")
  .option("delimiter", "\t")
  .option("quote", "\u0000")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("codec", "gzip")
  .save("s3://trfsmallfffile/FinancialLineItem/output")

  val FFRowCount =dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull.groupBy("DataPartition","StatementTypeCode").count

  FFRowCount.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rootTag", "FFFileType")
  .option("rowTag", "FFPhysicalFile")
  .save("s3://trfsmallfffile/FinancialLineItem/Descr")
```

Now files are saved in partitioned folder structure which is expected .

Now my requiremen is to rename all the part file and save it in one directory .
The name of the file will be as the name of the folder structure .

For example i have one file saved in `folder/DataPartition=Japan/PartitionYear=1971/part-00001-87a61115-92c9-4926-a803-b46315e55a08.c000.csv.gz`

Now i want my file name to be

```
Japan.1971.1.txt.gz
Japan.1971.2.txt.gz
```

I have done this in java map-reduce after my job is completed then i was reading HDFS files system and then moved it into different location as renamed file name .

But how do to the this in AWS S3 files system in spark SCALA .

As far as i have research there is no direct way to rename spark data frame output file name.

But there is implementation that can be done  in the job itself using `MultipleOutputs` as **saveAsHadoopFile** but how to do that ?.

I am looking for some sample code in scala

It is as like after completing job we need to read the file from s3,reame it  and move it to some other location .

Comment: Why don't you just read it with another job an reformat the name ?

Comment: e.g. val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("S3Test")
      .getOrCreate() 
    val file = spark.read.text(args(0)).rdd   in args(0) you put the s3 path you want to read the files from; If you have several Buckets you want to read from best you use the search api of AWS and pass the results [aws docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingJava.html)

Comment: @SUDARSHAN have added a code snippet. let me know that if that helped you -- thanks

Comment: Can you use something mentioned in this answer?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23368176/how-to-rename-a-file-in-amazon-s3-bucket

Answer (score 3):

```
val tempOutPath = "mediamath.dir"
headerDf.union(outDf)
  .repartition(1)
  .write
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .format("text")
  .option("codec", "gzip")
  .save(tempOutPath)

import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
val sc = spark.sparkContext
val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
val file = fs.globStatus(new Path("mediamath.dir/part*.gz"))(0).getPath.getName

fs.rename(new Path("mediamath.dir/" + file), new Path(<aws-s3-path>))
```

Here is my code snippet please see if this helps you.

Comment: getting this exception `error: value getPath is not a member of Array[org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus]`

Comment: file system is `S3`not `HDFS`

Comment: It doesn't matter that the FS is s3, it's the same API. Try it before dismisisng Jai's work, which looks OK to me, at a glance

Answer (score 1):

> AFAIK, If you are looking to rename file/object in S3 bucket directly, **It's not
> possible.**
>
> You can achieve the `rename = copy to target + delete source`

#### First let's extract the filename from source

```
def prepareNewFilename(oldFilename: String) = {

  val pattern = raw".*/DataPartition=%s/PartitionYear=%s/part-%s.*\.%s"
    .format("([A-Za-z]+)", "([0-9]+)", "([0-9]+)", "([a-z]+)")
    .r

  val pattern(country, year, part, extn) = oldFilename

  "%s.%s.%s.%s.%s".format(country, year, part, "txt", extn)
} 

val oldFilename = "folder/DataPartition=Japan/PartitionYear=1971/part-00001-87a61115-92c9-4926-a803-b46315e55a08.c000.csv.gz"

val newFilename = prepareNewFilename(oldFilename)
//newFilename: String = Japan.1971.00001.txt.gz
```

#### Code to rename the file/object in S3 in bucket

```
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder

val s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient()

try {
  s3.copyObject(sourceBkt, oldFilename, targetBkt, newFilename)
  s3.deleteObject(sourceBkt, oldFilename)
} catch {
  case e: AmazonServiceException =>
    System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage)
    System.exit(1)
}
```

Comment: Hello Sir ..Can you please have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48670551/adding-part-of-the-parent-schema-column-to-child-in-nested-json-in-spark-data-fr