# Rename and Move S3 files based on their folders name in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have spark output in a s3 folders and I want to move all s3 files from that output folder to another location ,but while moving I want to rename the files .

For example I have files in S3 folders like below

[image]

Now I want to rename all files and put into another directory,but the name of the files would be like below

```
Fundamental.FinancialStatement.FinancialStatementLineItems.Japan.1971-BAL.1.2017-10-18-0439.Full.txt
Fundamental.FinancialStatement.FinancialStatementLineItems.Japan.1971-BAL.2.2017-10-18-0439.Full.txt
Fundamental.FinancialStatement.FinancialStatementLineItems.Japan.1971-BAL.3.2017-10-18-0439.Full.txt
```

Here Fundamental.FinancialStatementis constant in all the files  `2017-10-18-0439` current date time .

This is what I have tried so far but not able to get folder name and loop through all files

```
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs._

val src = new Path("s3://trfsmallfffile/Segments/output")
val dest = new Path("s3://trfsmallfffile/Segments/Finaloutput")
val conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration   // assuming sc = spark context
val fs = src.getFileSystem(conf)
//val file = fs.globStatus(new Path("src/DataPartition=Japan/part*.gz"))(0).getPath.getName
//println(file)
val status = fs.listStatus(src)    

status.foreach(filename => {
               val a = filename.getPath.getName.toString()
                println("file name"+a)
                //println(filename)
             })
```

This gives me below output

```
    file nameDataPartition=Japan
file nameDataPartition=SelfSourcedPrivate
file nameDataPartition=SelfSourcedPublic
file name_SUCCESS
```

This gives me folders details not files inside the folder.

Reference is taken from here [Stack Overflow Refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48200035/how-rename-s3-files-not-hdfs-in-spark-scala/48223470?noredirect=1#comment83543229_48223470)

Comment: did you try using `fs.listFiles` and then `map` over it to rename each file?

Comment: @philantrovert  Yes but extracting folders name and then moving I am not able to do ..Can you please put some sample code

Comment: I don't understand. Once you do `fs.rename(src, dest)`, wouldn't `dest` become the folder name under which all the files are that need to be renamed. Apologies if I'm missing something. I'm behind a proxy and I can't see the image.

Comment: @philantrovert I have updated mu code please have a look

Comment: Arthav: debugging individual lines of code on stack overflow is not a viable development practice. I'd recommend an IDE like IntelliJ IDEA, scalatest for the tests, and setting breakpoints. Your code is broken, which is the kind of thing step-by-step debugging is going to tell you.

Comment: @SteveLoughran yes you are right ..I need to use that ...Currently I am using as script in zeppelin note book ..

Comment: Hello Atharv, did this work for you.? please release the solution here so that I can refer it for my issue. thanks

Comment: @Manoranjan yes it is working for me

Comment: was that working in your local or is it only working in aws cloud systems.?

Comment: @Manoranjan in local as well as in AWS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting directory because you have sub dir level in s3 .

```
/*/* to go in subdir .
```

Try this

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._

val src = new Path("s3://trfsmallfffile/Segments/Output/*/*")
val dest = new Path("s3://trfsmallfffile/Segments/FinalOutput")
val conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration   // assuming sc = spark context
val fs = src.getFileSystem(conf)

val file = fs.globStatus(new Path("s3://trfsmallfffile/Segments/Output/*/*"))


  for (urlStatus <- file) {
    //println("S3 FILE PATH IS ===:" + urlStatus.getPath)
    val partitioName=urlStatus.getPath.toString.split("=")(1).split("\\/")(0).toString
    val finalPrefix="Fundamental.FinancialLineItem.Segments."
    val finalFileName=finalPrefix+partitioName+".txt"
    val dest = new Path("s3://trfsmallfffile/Segments/FinalOutput"+"/"+finalFileName+ " ")
    fs.rename(urlStatus.getPath, dest)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me in past

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration 
val path = "s3://<bucket>/<directory>"
val fs = FileSystem.get(new java.net.URI(path), spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
fs.listStatus(new Path(path))
```

The list status provides all the files in the s3 directory

Comment: no it does not gives me files it lists only folders details