# Renaming all otput files in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm using spark java to create serval xml files from large dataset.

So far I have a code like this :

```
dataframe
                .repartition(partitions)
                .write()
                .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
                .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
                .option("rootTag", "citations")
                .option("rowTag", "citation")
                .mode("overwrite")
                .save("s3a://myfolder/output");
```

This code creates serval output files, and the number of that files is equal to `partitions`.

The problem is that these files are named like this:  `part-0000.xml, part-0001.xml, etc`

I want to rename this files, but I **don't want** to use `.repartition(1)`, because I need output to be in multiple files.

I know there are similar questions on stackoverflow like this : [How to rename spark data frame output file in AWS in spark SCALA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46703623/how-to-rename-spark-data-frame-output-file-in-aws-in-spark-scala)
but none of them solves my problem.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks