# How to rename a folder by prefix in s3 using PHP sdk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on a project, now i need to rename a key using its prefix in s3 php sdk api. i couldn't find it, if any can help. Thanks

```
    function moveFile($oldPath,$newPath){
$oKey = $this->getKey($oldPath);
$nKey = $this->getKey($newPath);

try{
    // Copy an object.
    $this->o->copyObject(array(
        'Bucket'     => $this->bucket,
        'ACL' => 'public-read',
        'Key'        => $nKey,
        'CopySource' => "{$this->bucket}/{$oKey}"
    ));

    $this->deleteFile($oldPath);

} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: the code is the function that is working for me to move a folder/key based on prefix. but i am wondering if there is any function to rename a folder? like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename files and folder in Amazon S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184720/how-to-rename-files-and-folder-in-amazon-s3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename `s3` files using below code :

```
$s3sdk = new Sdk($awsConfig);
$s3 = $s3sdk->createS3();
$s3->registerStreamWrapper();
rename($oldName, $newName);
```

both names need to contain the **full s3 path** e.g:

```
"s3://yourBucketName/path/to/file"
```

Basically `registerStreamWrapper()` enables PHP filesystem commands for s3 files.

Comment: Thanks your answer is also correct, but i did with the codes above i answered.

Comment: This does not work for folders, it only allows renaming a file.

Comment: @Namrata, at the time I answered in year 2017, it was working well.
have not tried recently, so you can find recent answeres instead.

Answer (score 1):

I did this, you guys answered late. i did it myself but LuFFy answer is also correct.

```
function renameFolder($oldPath,$newPath){
$oKey = $this->getKey($oldPath);
if(strpos($oKey,'/')==false){$oKey.='/';}
//echo '<br>oKey: '.$oKey.'<br>'; 
try{
    // Copy an object.
    /*$this->o->copyObject(array(
        'Bucket'     => $this->bucket,
        'ACL' => 'public-read',
        'Key'        => $nKey,
        'CopySource' => "{$this->bucket}/{$oKey}"
    ));*/

    $result = $this->o->listObjects([
        'Bucket' => $this->bucket, // REQUIRED
        'Prefix' => $oKey,
    ]); 

    foreach($result['Contents'] as $file){
        //echo '<br>objectKey: '.$file['Key'].'<br>';
        $nKey = str_replace($this->getLastKey($oldPath),$this->getLastKey($newPath),$file['Key']);
        //echo '<br>nKey: '.$nKey.'<br>';
        $this->o->copyObject(array(
            'Bucket'     => $this->bucket,
            'ACL' => 'public-read',
            'Key'        => $nKey,
            'CopySource' => "{$this->bucket}/".$file['Key'].""
        ));
    }

    $this->deleteDir($oldPath);

}catch(S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to rename existing files on the batch using below steps:

1. Lets say your **config/filesystems.php** looks like this:

```php
    'disks' => [
      's3_test_bucket' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key'    => env('AWS_KEY', 'your_aws_key_here'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET','your_aws_secret_here'),
            'region' =>  env('AWS_REGION', 'your_aws_region_here'),
            'version' => 'latest',
            'bucket'  => 'my-test-bucket',
      ],
    ];
```

2. Let's say, you have **my-test-bucket** on your AWS S3.
3. Lets say you have following files inside the my-test-bucket/test-directory directory.
   i.e.

   - test-files-1.csv
   - test-files-2.csv
   - test-files-3.csv
4. Call below function to rename existing files on a selected directory on S3 Bucket.

```php
    $directoryPath = 'test-directory';
    $storage = new MyStorageRepository();
    $storage->renameAnyExistingFilesOnImportDirectory('my-test-bucket', 'test-directory');
```

5. Output: files should be rename as below on my-test-bucket/test-directory directory:

   - test-files-1--1548870936.csv
   - test-files-2--1548870936.csv
   - test-files-3--1548870936.csv
6. Include the below library class or methods on your class and you should be good.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class MyStorageRepository
{
    public function renameAnyExistingFilesOnImportDirectory($bucket, $directoryPath)
    {
        $directoryPath = App::environment() . '/' . $directoryPath;
        $storage = Storage::disk('s3_test_bucket');

        $suffix = '--' . time(); // File suffix to rename.

        if ($storage->exists($directoryPath)) {
            $this->renameStorageDirectoryFiles($directoryPath, $storage, $suffix);
        }
    }

    private function getNewFilename($filename, $suffix = null)
    {
        $file = (object) pathinfo($filename);

        if (!$suffix) {
            $suffix = '--' . time();
        }

        return $file->dirname . '/' . $file->filename . $suffix . '.' . $file->extension;
    }

    private function renameStorageDirectoryFiles($directoryPath, $storage = null, $suffix = null, $filesystemDriver = null)
    {
        if (!$storage) {
            $storage = Storage::disk($filesystemDriver);
        }

        // List all the existing files from the directory
        $files = $storage->files($directoryPath);

        if (count($files) < 1 ) return false;

        foreach($files as $file) {
            // Get new filename
            $newFilename = Helpers::getNewFilename($file, $suffix);

            // Renamed the files
            $storage->move($file, $newFilename);
        }
    }
}
```