# Move files from one folder to another folder in aws S3 with ex_aws library in elixir

Tags: amazon-s3, elixir

I have a file present inside IN folder on S3 bucket with key as in/c05cf611db4b4a72a8a254fcf4355fb7-sample1.csv". Now I want to move this file inside another folder ARCHIEVE_IN so that it's key changes to archieve_in/c05cf611db4b4a72a8a254fcf4355fb7-sample1.csv".

Is there a way to achieve this functionality with the `ex_aws` library.

Comment: I don't think you can rename a file in S3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184720/how-to-rename-files-and-folder-in-amazon-s3. You'll need to copy and delete.

Comment: @Dogbert yes I think you are right, the only way to do so is to download the file, change it's name, upload it again, then delete the original file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename files and folder in Amazon S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184720/how-to-rename-files-and-folder-in-amazon-s3)

Answer (score 1):

[S3 doesn't have a built in "move" operation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184720/how-to-rename-files-and-folder-in-amazon-s3) You can instead use [ExAws.S3.put_object_copy](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_aws_s3/ExAws.S3.html#put_object_copy/5) to copy the file to a new place and then [ExAws.S3.delete_object](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_aws_s3/ExAws.S3.html#delete_object/3) to delete the old file.