# How to move all files (without using copy) and folder from one folder to another of S3 bucket in PHP ,Cannot use copy function

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have to move all files and folders from one folder to another of S3 bucket in php. I know a way to do the same thing is:

1. Get all objects list from the source folder
2. Copy all objects into destination folder
3. Delete all objects from source folder

Then I know AWS don't have folders with some sort of hierarchy, it's only buckets based but now a days have any option or updates.

I am using [Amazon S3 PHP Class](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class) version 0.4.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename files and folder in Amazon S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184720/how-to-rename-files-and-folder-in-amazon-s3)

Answer (score 4):

Amazon S3 does not have a 'move' command. The only choice is to **copy then delete**.

The copy command tells S3 to copy the object, without requiring any downloads. Therefore, it is fast and efficient.

While S3 doesn't use folders, it does understand **prefixes**. The full path is part of the filename (Key). So, for example:

- If you want to move `folder1/foo.txt` to `folder2/foo.txt`, then:
- Copy `folder1/foo.txt` to `folder2/foo.txt`
- Delete `folder1/foo.txt`

To use AWS with PHP, you should use the official [AWS SDK for PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comments .
i know copy then delete 
but i need short cut 
i want to move files directly without using copy delete

Comment: There is no shortcut. You could use the `aws s3 mv` command in the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), but underneath it is still copying and deleting. What do you consider to be a "shortcut" -- do you want something that runs fast, or are you just looking for some copy/delete code that somebody else has written?