# Amazon S3 filenames: Replace double spaces from all files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket on Amazon S3 with thousands of files that contain double spaces in their names.

How can I replace all the double spaces with one space?

like: `folder1/folder2/file  name.pdf` to `folder1/folder2/file name.pdf`

Comment: Copy the file from the original name / location to the target / desired one. Then delete the old file. Do that for every file.

Comment: but I have more than 4 thousand files

Comment: Then write a script for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184720/how-to-rename-files-and-folder-in-amazon-s3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the idea from @john-rotenstein

I build bash command that makes it in one line

```
aws s3 ls  --recursive s3://bucket-name | cut -c32- | grep "\/.*  .*" | (IFS='' ; while read -r line ; do aws s3 mv  s3://bucket-name/"$line"  s3://bucket-name/$(echo "$line" | xargs)  --recursive; done)
```

- get the list paths of the bucket
- cut the result to get the only file path
- search all paths that contain double spaces
- move to new path with one space

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1: Use a spreadsheet**

One 'cheat method' I sometimes use is to **create a spreadsheet** and then generate commands:

- Extract a list of all files with double-spaces:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucket-name --query 'Contents[].[Key]' --output text | grep '\ \ ' >file_list.csv
```

- Open the file in Excel
- Write a formula in Column B that creates a `aws s3 mv` command:

```
="aws s3 mv 's3://bucket-name/"&A1&"' 's3://bucket-name/"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"  "," ")&"'"
```

- Test it by copying the output and running it in a terminal
- If it works, Copy Down to the other rows, copy and paste all the commands into a shell script, then run the shell script

**Option 2: Write a script**

Or, you could write a script in your favourite language (eg Python) that will:

- List the bucket
- Loop through each object
- If the object Key has double-spaces:

  - Copy the object to a new Key
  - Delete the original object